# Enter if loop for no apparent reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
mylist = [['apple',1],['banana',2],['byrne',3]]
x =  0
for y in mylist:
    print(x)
    print(mylist[x][0])
    if 'byrne' or 'apple' == mylist[x][0]:
        print('hi')
    x += 1
```

prints out:

0
apple
hi
1
banana
hi
2
byrne
hi

The question: why does it enter the if loop for x = 1?

If i put just one string for entering the loop i get one hi, as expected.

Comment: note: `if` is not a loop.

Comment: `if mylist[x][0] in ['byrne', 'apple']:`. Your code is being evaluated `'byrne' or OTHERSTUFF` and is always true since `bool('byrne')` evaluates as true.

Comment: @Nice In other words, Python does not interpret `a or b == c`as being the same as `(a == c) or (b == c)`.